# Blob to azure sql db load

Tags: azure-data-factory

blob contain Hive Partition table data partition created on Year, month and day.
Container look like Year=2016/ Months=1/Day-1 - 0000_1(File) to Day-31 - 0000_31(File) 
Like this we have 3 months inside year and each month contain days folder and ear day folder contain a file.

Now we want o put that data into a azure sql Db table which is not partitioned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right , you have blobs with the structure 
2016/03/01_001
2016/03/01_003 
and the intend is to copy the data to SQL Azure . I am assuming that the blob structure is the same on all the files . 
I suggest

1:Use the GetMetadata activity and get all the blob info

2:Use a foreach activity to read one blob at a time

3:Inside the foreach add a copy activity source being blob and sink SQL Azure .